# Processing- Waiting for Android device

Tags: android, processing

I've tried this on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu, and I can't get past Processing waiting for a device.

I've followed the instructions at http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/processing-cant-get-connected-to-phone-emulator-need-help.html and I still can't get it to work on either OS

Comment: Can you give us more information? What have you tried? What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: I've dowloaded the Android SDKs and Processing a la http://processing.org/tutorials/android/ ; when I try to run a simple Processing program as an Android app it fails. I've let Processing know what android emulator port to look for and it still can't find the "android device" to run the simple program on

Comment: Have you created an AVD in AVD-Manager.exe?

Comment: Yeah- it sits there as Processing waits for a device and Processing always fails to find it. I've changed the preferences.txt for Processing to look at the emulator port the AVD is running on and it's still not finding it.